# why cannot display value that is generate by another thread on a C# web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

on a C# web page, I have a button, a textbox and a label, then I want to accept user input from the textbox and do factorial in another thread then get the result and display it on the label of the web page. I can get the correct calculation result but I cannot see the result on the web page. please see my code below:

following code is in the webForm1.aspx.cs:

```
public delegate void printResultDelegate(int target);
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printResultDelegate del = new printResultDelegate(getResultCallback);
    Number num = new Number(6, del);
    Thread workThread = new Thread(num.calculate);
    workThread.Start();
}

public void getResultCallback(int result)
{
    TextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    Logger.log("Call back function invoked, result: " + result.ToString());
}
```

below code is in the Number.cs:

```
public class Number
{
    private int _target;
    private printResultDelegate _del;
    private int reslut;
    public Number(int tar, printResultDelegate del)
    {
        this._target = tar;
        this._del = del;
    }

    public void calculate()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < _target; i++)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        Logger.log("Thread method called, sum is : " + sum.ToString());
        _del(sum);
    }
}
```

so, does anyone know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You are using `threading` which means the thread result might executed after page is rendered.

Comment: so, is there a way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: You could wait for the result to be returned before continuing execution.